MFC Support in Visual Studio
I have a VC++ 6.0 application that looks rather dated and doesn't build on anything later than Windows 7.  I'm worried that MFC will not be supported moving forward as I upgrade to newer versions of Visual Studio and Windows.
This application has been used for 25 years and will probably still be used in the next 25 years.  I don't want to scrap the code base (25,000+ lines of code) and start again unless I have to.  I fear that Microsoft will remove support for MFC completely in years to come.  Several COM components would need support as well.
Is there anyone out there that knows what Microsoft's intentions are in respect of MFC/COM support?  Is there a roadmap of any kind that will help me make an informed decision?
I have browsed the internet but got ambiguous results.

MFC is still officially maintained and supported. I don't think it will disappear anytime soon and it will also continue to work during a very long time since it's still used by big software (including Microsoft's ones). However, officially supported doesn't mean much, no one from Microsoft will help you (unless you pay big support bucks) plus it's open source. It's more that the technology (Win32's user) is a bit outdated and doesn't change. However, I would definitely port the code to recent Visual Studio + MFC (2022 as of today) and continue to keep on with latest VS versions. Small work.

In my experience, the update assistant has improved far more in VS 2022 compared to, for example, VS 2013. There are not so much new features to MFC since VS 2008, but the compiler is still improving, justifying a recommendation to move to VS 2022. E.g. Edit&Continue was revived as "Hot Reload" and works quite well. I can't imagine any good reason to stop support for MFC by Microsoft unless they stop support for C++, which is highly unlikely.

Currently the latest stable MFC version is 14 and it was released on 2019.According to MSFT it will have a 10-year support lifetime so it will be supported at least to 2029 and there are no signs of MFC being deprecated.
